# Groovy: invoke method instead of set field

Tags: groovy

I have a class which has a field the same name as a method on that class.
The problem I'm having is groovy is using the field instead of the method.

The class is javax.ws.rs.core.Response and the method/field is status.
I am unable to call the status(...) method with just: Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST) to have it return a ResponseBuilder.

Is there a way to force groovy to use the method in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an example of this failing?

I wrote this quick test:

```
class Test {
  String status
  void status( String status ) {
    println "called method"
  }
}

new Test().status( 'tim' )
```

And that prints `called method` as I would expect (it doesn't try to call the property)

Comment: See: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build().

The build() method doesnt exist because Response.status(...) is returning an implementation of Response, not ResponseBuilder as it should.

Comment: I can see the class, but I cannot see how it could be returning `Response` if you are calling it how you say you are calling it.  That's why I asked for an example, so that I can a) verify the problem you say your are having, and b) see if you have errors in your code

Comment: I cannot seem to get this error with simple code. My code is just as follows: return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build() where Response is javax.ws.rs.core.Response and Status.BAD_REQUEST is an Response$Status enum value.

It appears to be conflicting with the getStatus() method on Response. Perhaps the problem is with Response being an abstract java class, but it should be calling: 
        public ResponseBuilder status(Status status) {
            return status((StatusType)status);
        };

Comment: @Steven That leads me to suspect it is an issue with your code (if it works for a simple example). If it is being passed attributes, it won't be calling `getStatus` so long as you have the parentheses as you say in your above comment

Comment: Seems it was just eclipse compiling the class weirdly. If I build it in gradle it seems fine. Weird...

Comment: Maybe try a 'clean' from Eclipse? (Not sure this even exists, I'm not an Eclipse user) :-/